# Is there any way to add large list items in SQLite table in flutter?

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart

I am learning flutter, I am making an app that has checkbox list items on the home page. So, User can check the items and save them. I want to use the SQLite database to save user checked items. But how can I create a database table if I am having lots of items? Should I add each item in the column?

```
void _createDb(Database db, int newVersion) async {
  await db.execute('CREATE TABLE $AppTable($Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO INCREMENT, $Item1 Integer, $Item2 Integer, : : $Itemn Integer )' ); 
}
```

Or is there any way to do this? Because I am having so many list items how can I create a data table for this? Suggest me a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, welcome to Stack Overflow. SQLite works for small amounts of data and is a great introduction to database management.

You should take some time to read up on database design and normalization in particular, but you will want to create a table with the options, another table with users, and a third one with the options chosen by the users.

```
create table user (user_id integer, name varhcar, other varchar);

create table options (option_id integer, display_text varchar);

create table options_chosen ( user_id integer, option_id integer);

insert into user values (1, 'Charles Aznavour', 'Famous French singer');

insert into options values (1, 'Rock');
insert into options values (2, 'Pop');
insert into options values (3, 'Hip Hop');


insert into options_chosen values (1, 2); 
insert into options_chosen values (1, 3);
```

You then access the data as follows:

```
select usr.name, opt.display_text options_chosen
from user usr
 inner join options_chosen chn
  on chn.user_id = usr.user_id
 inner join options opt
  on opt.option_id = chn.option_id;
```

You can insert many rows at a time into SQLite as follows:

```
insert into options_chosen values (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), <...> ;
```

In Dart, you're going to want to use `Batch` to insert multiple records.
Check out [this example](https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite/example/lib/batch_test_page.dart), modified as follows for your need:

```
batch = db.batch();
batch.rawInsert('INSERT INTO options_chosen VALUES (?, ?)', ['item1', 'item2']);
batch.insert('options_chosen ', {'user_id': 1, 'option_id': 2});
results = await batch.commit();
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply LarsSkaug. But how can I add my 100 items to the table column? Is it possible in sqlite

Comment: Absolutely. I updated my answer with the following addition: insert into options_chosen values (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), <...> ;

Comment: can I  add directly a map? Finally, I need a table like this. Id - item1 - item2 ... itemn .

Comment: Lars Skaug, Sorry for too many questions. Here is my problem I have a map having items as keys and booleans as values.(map(item:true)). there are 100 items in map. So how can I create a Table for  this.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Dart but you should be using `Batch`. You can directly insert a Map that way. I have updated my answer with a reference to how it may be used.

Comment: ThankYou-#LarsSkaug